# Rambam, Shkiah, and Tzet HaKokhavim

Tags: halacha, rambam, zemanim, evening-night

In the dispute between the Geonim and Rabbenu Tam over the definition of nightfall, I have seen the Rambam claimed by either side - each claiming that in the Mishneh Torah he held like them.

My question is: How does the Rambam hold about *shkiah* and *tzet ha-kokhavim*? Does he hold of one *shekiah* or two? Does he equate *shkiah* with the actual sinking of the sun below the horizon, with the appearance of three stars, or both? Does he hold like the Geonim or like Rabbenu Tam?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in manuscript versions of _Mishneh Torah_ he effectively defines _Tzet ha-Kokhavim_ as being about 20 minutes after the _Sheqi'ah_. (I always understood him to equate the _Sheqi'ah_ "with the actual sinking of the sun below the horizon", but am not sure there's an explicit source for that.)

Comment: Maybe he disagrees with both Rabbenu Tam and the Gra? Are there only two options?

Answer (score 1):

Rav Nachum Rabinovitch of Yeshivat Birkat Moshe in Maale Adumim interprets the Rambam as refering to sunset as shekiah and cites Rabbi Avraham ben HaRambam also as saying as much: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/shana/rabinovits-2.htm

Comment: Nice find. However, Rabbenu also held of sunset being sheqiah. But he also held of two "sheqiahs": one when the sun sets and the other when the stars come out. So, would this be conclusive? Why or why not? Thanks. Kol tuv.